# Convert JavaPairRDD<ImmutableBytesWritable, Result> to JavaRDD<String>

Tags: java, apache-spark, hbase, rdd, java-pair-rdd

I am trying to read the data from HBase using Apache Spark. I want to only scan one specific column. I am creating an RDD of my HBase data like below

```
SparkConf sparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName("HBaseRead").setMaster("local[2]");
JavaSparkContext sc = new JavaSparkContext(sparkConf);
Configuration conf = HBaseConfiguration.create();
conf.set("hbase.zookeeper.quorum", "localhost:2181");

String tableName = "myTable";

conf.set(TableInputFormat.INPUT_TABLE, tableName);
conf.set(TableInputFormat.SCAN_COLUMN_FAMILY, "myCol");


 JavaPairRDD<ImmutableBytesWritable, Result> hBaseRDD = sc.newAPIHadoopRDD(conf, TableInputFormat.class,
        ImmutableBytesWritable.class, Result.class);
```

Here is where I want to convert the `JavaPairRDD` to `JavaRDD` of string.

```
JavaRDD<String> rdd = ...
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get `JavaRDD<String>` using `map` function like below.

```
import org.apache.spark.api.java.function.Function;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.Bytes;
import scala.Tuple2;

JavaRDD<String> javaRDD = javaPairRdd.map(new Function<Tuple2<ImmutableBytesWritable,Result>, String>() {
    @Override
    public String call(Tuple2<ImmutableBytesWritable, Result> tuple) throws Exception {
        Result result = tuple._2;
        String rowKey = Bytes.toString(result.getRow());//row key
        String fName = Bytes.toString(result.getValue(Bytes.toBytes("myColumnFamily"), Bytes.toBytes("firstName")));//firstName column 
        return fName;
    }       
});
```